# Flash Player Bug?

Tags: safari, adobe-flash

I was trying to listen to some music on MySpace, and it told me
[image: Screenshot]

I refreshed the page, but it still came up with this. I restarted my browser, but the same thing happened. When I tried updating my Flash Player, I noticed that it was version 10.3.183.18. When I tried installing it, it told me that it wouldn't install because I had a newer version of flash installed.

*What the heck is going on?!!*

Comment: Correct question. An intelligent software should provide one working advice. An information which starts with "try the following" looks like a robot random answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try running [Adobe's Uninstaller](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-mac-os.html) then reinstalling Flash.

Once you have, check your [installed Flash version](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) and make sure it's 11.2.202.228.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the newer version installed and is waiting for a reboot in order to finalize the update. if not i would say completely uninstall flash as it's decided to bug on you, reboot then reinstall the latest version.
Hope this helps!
-theternalnoob

Comment: The Flash plug-in doesn't require a full restart, just for the browsers that use it to quit and re-open.